# Harmonic Voices Alongside Counterpoint

Tags: harmony, composition, analysis, counterpoint

I'm writing a piece for a rather large ensemble:

- full string section
- SATB choir plus soloists
- 2 of oboe, bassoon, and trombone
- c-g timpani

In one of the sections, the chorus sings a fugato while the orchestra is supposed to support them in some way. This is proving to be very difficult. I could, of course, have them simply double the choir, but that wouldn't do much to add support, not to mention being quite lazy.

For example, Mozart's Requiem did this beautifully at the choir's first entrance, with the orchestra playing a dotted rhythm that combined beautifully with the fugato/stretto-like section in the choir.

**How is this done in practice?** Whenever I attempt to add anything in the orchestra, it always clashes with something in one of the 4 melodically independent voices in the choir. How do you add supportive voices to an already contrapuntal section?

PS: I have attempted to analyze that section of the Requiem to attempt to figure this out myself, but I'm not very good at analysis, so that attempt was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you're willing to expand your range a bit, look into Bach's cantatas. Dozens of them open with instrumental sinfonias to which a four-part contrapuntal chorus is later added (*Choreinbau*).

Comment: Your recent post led me back to this one. Was my answer of use? And if not, what would make it more useful?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, your answer to this question was very useful. I finished the piece that I mentioned in this question, and your answer was of good use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thought to analyze the Mozart is going in the right direction. Below is a reduction of the Introit's choral entrance, mm. 8–14.

- The parts are rhythmically simplified and combined to show doublings.
- The clarino (valveless trumpet) and timpani are omitted to simplify the reduction. Clarino II and timpani double each other and comprise a very minor variation on clarino I. All of the pitches in the three parts occur in other instruments, but not always the same instruments.

**Except for the violins, every instrumental part doubles a vocal part.**
[image: Introit reduction]

**The violins are the reason it doesn't just sound like doubling.** They add rhythmic interest by playing on the 2nd and 4th sixteenth of every beat, but pitch-wise they either double another part, or they play a chord tone not otherwise covered. Even though they double other parts, however, **they don't double any single part, thus creating a new contrapuntal part in terms of both pitch and rhythm.**

Comment: You're welcome.  "Valveless" trumpets would have been nonsense in Mozart's day, since valves hadn't yet been invented.  Nitpicks aside, this is of course the correct answer.  Bach's and Handel's festive choral/orchestral works also have many examples of instrumental doublings shifting from one voice to another: sometimes the top voice in the orchestra doubles the soprano but sometimes it doubles the alto at the octave, often switching in the middle of a phrase.  I'm less familiar with the practices of 19th-century composers.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer to anyone who hopes to write something similar. If I may, I'd also point out that when we take "vertical slices" of beats 1 and 3, we hear (mostly) triads. This realization can help immensely when writing multi-voiced counterpoint.

Comment: Another useful thing is to use one choir of the orchestra ( the strings, the woodwinds, etc) to play a full chord on certain beats, resting between.  They can support your voices but not get in the way of your counterpoint